# Ruby: generating new Regexps from strings

Tags: ruby, regex, string

Is there any way to convert String to Regexp (in Ruby)? Let's say:

```
'example' ---> /example/
```

My purpose is generating Regexps dynamically.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
regexp = Regexp.new(string)
```

or

```
regexp = /#{string}/
```

If it is possible that `string` has special characters, then:

```
regexp = Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(string))
```

or

```
regexp = /#{Regexp.escape(string)}/
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also write...

```
regex = Regexp.compile(string)
```

...which is a very descriptive name. This method compiles the source code (string) into a nondeterministic finite automaton (regex). The NFA can then be reused over and over.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `/#{your variable}/`